# Set lookup in Nodejs does not seem to have O(1)

Tags: node.js, performance, hash, set, v8

I wrote a test to test the lookup speed of Set in Nodejs (v8.4).

```
const size = 5000000;
const lookups = 1000000;

const set = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    set.add(i);
}

const samples = [];
for (let i = 0; i < lookups; i++) {
    samples.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * size));
}


const start = Date.now();
for (const key of samples) {
    set.has(key);
}

console.log(`size: ${size}, time: ${Date.now() - start}`);
```

After running it with size = 5000, 50000, 500000, and 5000000, the result is surprising to me:

```
size: 5000, time: 29
size: 50000, time: 41
size: 500000, time: 81
size: 5000000, time: 130
```

I expected the time it takes is relatively constant. But it increases substantially as the number of items in the Set increases. Isn't the lookup supposed to be O(1)? What am I missing here?

**Update 1:**

After reading some comments and answers, I understand the point everyone is trying to make here. Maybe my question should be 'What is causing the increase in time?'. In hash map implementation, with the same number of lookups, the reason for increase in lookup time can only be there are more key collisions.

**Update 2:**

After more research, here is what I found:

- V8 uses ordered hash table for both Set and Map implementation
- According to [this link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User:Jorend/Deterministic_hash_tables), there are performance impact on the lookup time for ordered hash map, while unordered hash map's performance stays constant.
- However, V8's ordered hash table implementation is based on [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User:Jorend/Deterministic_hash_tables), and that doesn't seem to add any overhead to the look up time with increasing number of items.

Comment: O(1) means that the operation time is constant, but not necessarily the real time. You can write an O(n) sorting algorithm using timeouts, but it takes much longer than an O(n^2) algorithm without timeouts.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether the JS `Set` implementation is actually O(1) or not (I'm not sure it is), you should not expect O(1) operations to result in speed that is identical across calls. It is a means of measuring the operation complexity rather than the actual throughput speed.

To demonstrate this, consider the use case of sorting an array of numbers. You can sort using `array.sort` which I believe is O(n * log(n)) in Node.js. You can also create a (bad, but amusing) O(n) implementation using timeouts (ignore complexity of adding to the array, etc):

```
// input data
let array = [
  681, 762, 198, 347, 340,
   73, 989, 967, 409, 752,
  660, 914, 711, 153, 691,
   35, 112, 907, 970,  67
];

// buffer of new 
let sorted = [];

// O(n) sorting algorithm
array.forEach(function (num) {
  setTimeout(sorted.push.bind(sorted, num), num);
});

// ensure sort finished
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(sorted);
}, 2000);
```

Of course, the first implementation is faster - but in terms of complexity, the second one is "better". The point is that you should only really be using O to estimate, it does not guarantee any specific amount of time. If you called the O(n) above with an array of 20 numbers (so the same length) but it had only two digit numbers, it would be a large execution time difference.

Stupid example, but it should hopefully support the point I'm trying to make :)

Comment: Just to confirm: V8's implementation of `Set` lookup is in fact O(1). -- That sorting implementation is hilarious! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Caching and memory locality. V8's implementation of `Set` lookup has O(1) theoretical complexity, but real hardware has its own constraints and characteristics. Specifically, not every memory access has the same speed. Theoretical complexity analysis is only concerned with the number of operations, not the speed of each operation.

**Update for updated question:**

This answers your updated question! When you make many requests to a small `Set`, it will be likely that the CPU has cached the relevant chunks of memory, making many of the lookups faster than they would be if the data had to be retrieved from memory. There don't have to be more collisions for this effect to happen; it is simply the case that accessing a small memory region repeatedly is faster than spreading out the same number of accesses over a large memory region.

In fact, you can measure the same effect (with smaller magnitude) with an array:

```
const size = 5000000;
const lookups = 1000000;

const array = new Array(size);
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  array[i] = 1;
}

const start = Date.now();
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lookups; i++) {
  var sample = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
  result += array[sample];
}
const end = Date.now();
console.log(`size: ${size}, time: ${end - start}`);
```

A million lookups of random indices on a 5,000-element array will be faster than a million lookups of random indices on a 5,000,000 element array. 
The reason is that for a smaller data structure, there's a greater likelihood that the random accesses will read elements that are already in the CPU's cache.

Comment: I simply changed the line: `result += array[sample]` to `result = array[sample]` and the speed are the sample for all array sizes. I suspect that the time increase in your code is not from the lookup time.

Answer (score -1):

In theory you could be right, a `Set` could have a lookup of O(1), but the JS `set` definition is very specific on the algorithm. See [ECMA Script definition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set.prototype.has). There is a loop over all elements included.

Try have a look at various `HashSet` implementation you can find for example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=hashset), there might be one with O(1) `.has`-speed.

Comment: Uh, the measurements in the question are certainly not looping over ever single element in the Set.  The average access time if that was the case would be proportional to O(1/2 N), but that's not the case at all with the measured numbers as the set size goes up by 100x and the access time goes up by 3x.

Comment: The spec actually requires "better than O(n)" for `Set` operations: "Set objects must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection." (https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set-objects) The algorithm you linked to only specifies functional semantics, not actual implementation complexity.